# Retain the State of iPhone Application after exit

Tags: iphone

How can I retain the state of an iPhone after it has exited. What is the easy way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question is when do you save? The answer is in two places (assuming you want to support 3.x and 4.x devices).

First, for OS 3.x devices (and OS 4 devices that don't multi-task):

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

And second, for OS 4.x devices:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

You need to do this on iOS4 devices because if the app is shutdown while it's in the background it is just killed; you never see the applicationWillTerminate message.

As for the how, well it depends on how complex your app is. I created a simple protocol that I implement for each view controller that might want to save its state:

```
@protocol SaveState

- (NSData*) saveState;
- (id) initWithSaveState:(NSData*)data;

@end
```

It saves the state by looping through view controllers in the main navigation controller and calling the save state method. It then does the reverse in the applicationDidFinishLaunching: method. [More information on my blog](http://www.zx81.org.uk/computing/software/iphone-dev-saving-state.html).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. This really helped me. I will get back to you if I face any other problems.

Answer (score 1):

In your application delegate, you can define the [`-applicationWillTerminate:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW28) method to include code to save application state data.

```
- (void) applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // save state to data model here...
}
```

Your data model is up to you. For example, this could be a set of [user defaults](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html) or a Core Data store.

The next time the app is started, you could check for saved state data in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` and initialize the app appropriately.

If you are using iOS 4 and your application supports multitasking features, you will get some of the state saving functionality "for free" because [the app resigns focus](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW9), instead of terminating.

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks.Let me say, I have four tabs and currently I am in First tab and at sixth screen,(six navigations I have done), how can I store the info easily to identify, which one I should open when user opens the App, the next time. I assume that once the App is launched the next time, I will have to programmatically  traverse tot that particular View?  Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Correct, you save a "tree representation" of where your user left off, and then go back there when the app is relaunched.